# How do I get string values from my jtable?

Tags: java, string, netbeans, jtable

I have my table filled in with strings and I'm trying to access them. I've tried '.getValueAt' but it gives me an error.

code is

```
'if (dayOfTheWeek=="Thursday"){
    int thursdayCOUNT=0;
    String[] THURSDAYSHOW=null;
    while (thursdayCOUNT<10){
         THURSDAYSHOW[thursdayCOUNT] = (String) timetable.getValueAt(thursdayCOUNT, 3);
         thursdayCOUNT=thursdayCOUNT+1;
          }'
```

error is 'Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at my.UI.schedulerUI.jButton1ActionPerformed(schedulerUI.java:1401)'

Comment: Post code and error you are getting...

Comment: ' (dayOfTheWeek=="Thursday"){
        int thursdayCOUNT=0;
        String[] THURSDAYSHOW=null;
        while (thursdayCOUNT<10){
             THURSDAYSHOW[thursdayCOUNT] = (String) timetable.getValueAt(thursdayCOUNT, 3);
             thursdayCOUNT=thursdayCOUNT+1;
              }'

Comment: error is Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at my.UI.UI.jButton1ActionPerformed(UI.java:1401)

Comment: Put it in your question not a comment please.

Comment: First, please highlight the code and click on the **`{}`** button to format as code inside your question, along with creating proper line breaks and indents.  Second, what line is throwing the nullpointer?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting, the nullpointer is obvious now.  You need to initialize your `String[]`

Comment: isn't it initialized in the 3rd line?

Comment: Well it is initialized to `null` which is why the 5th line is causing an exception

Comment: what, for example, could i initialize it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are initializing your `String[]` to null.  You need to make it a `new String["Some number goes here"]`

It looks like you are using `10` as your length of iteration, so that could be how big you make the array:

`String[] THURSDAYSHOW= new String[10];`

This then can be easily followed up with a for loop to replace your while loop.  Here is a full example:

```
if (dayOfTheWeek.equals("Thursday")){
    String[] THURSDAYSHOW= new String[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < THURSDAYSHOW.length; i++)
    {
         THURSDAYSHOW[i] = (String) timetable.getValueAt(i, 3);
    }
}
```

One last note, use `.equals()` when comparing Strings.